# Custom Protocol Handling in Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-mobile

We are developing a Windows Phone 7 app. I was wondering if anyone has successfully (if yes, how) managed to register a custom protocol handler. 
e.g. if the device sees a url like myapp://dosomething.com/aaa it knows to open the app when the user clicks on this URL.

Comment: Hi Nikhil, did you find an answer to your question? I'm searching for an answer too ..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried playing with [RegisterPrefix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.registerprefix(v=VS.95).aspx)/[IWebRequestCreate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.iwebrequestcreate(v=VS.95).aspx) ? Depending on how/where do you want to use it later, it may be just the thing you are asking for.

Here's an example: [How to register own protocol using the WebBrowser control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689237/how-to-register-own-protocol-using-the-webbrowser-control)